# Why is the time function working differently in both these cases?

Tags: python, time

I am solving Problem 14 of Project Euler and I wrote 2 programs, one which is optimised and the other which is not. I've even imported the time module to calculate the time taken, but it's not working properly. it works fine in the unoptimised code:

```
import time
start = time.time()
def collatz(n):
    chain=1
    while(n>1):
        chain+=1
        if(n%2==0):
            n/=2
        else:
            n = 3*n+1
    return chain

maxChain = 0
num=0
counter = 10**6

while(counter>13):
    coll = collatz(counter)
    if(coll > maxChain):
        maxChain = coll
        num = counter
    counter-=1
end = time.time()
print("Time taken:",end-start)
print(start+', '+ end)
```

the output is:

```
Time taken: 47.83728861808777
1591290440.8452923, 1591290488.682581
```

But in my other code:

```
import time
start = time.time()

dict = {n:0 for n in range(1,10**6)}
dict[1], dict[2] = 1,2

for i in range(3,10**6):
    counter = 0
    start = i

    while(i > 1):
        #Have we already encountered this sequence?
        if(i < start):
            dict[start] = counter + dict[i]
            break
        
        if(i%2==0):
            i/=2
        else:
            i = 3*i+1
        counter += 1


end = time.time()
print('Time taken:',end-start)
print(start+', '+end)
```

the output is:

```
Time taken: 1590290651.4527032
999999, 1591290650.4527032
```

The start time in the second program is 999999 while the end time is fine. this problem doesn't occur in the first program, I don't know why this is happening?

Comment: You reuse the variable.  `start = i`

Comment: @Ciero, thank you so much. You can add that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translated from comment:

You can see in the second version of the code you shadow/reuse the variable `start`, using it for a counter.  Thus the `999999` in your output, and the strange results.

Renaming it to anything else will fix you right up =)